# Syntax of ng-repeat ng-class conditional

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I'm trying to resolve the following html so that it applies the css class stored in  `$root.buttonClass='btn-primary'` (for example)

```
<li ng-controller="controllerCtrl">
   <a ng-class="{'$root.buttonClass':viewingContext=='{{entity}}'}" 
      ng-repeat="entity in entities" 
      ng-click="setContext(entity)" 
     type="">
     <span class="label bg-info pull-right" 
           ng-class="{hidden:viewingContext!='{{entity}}', show:viewingContext=='{{entity}}'}">
           viewing</span>
           {{entity}}</a>
</li>
```

The controller is fairly simple:

```
  $scope.setContext = function (entity) {
    console.log('set the context as: ' + entity);
    if (entity == $scope.entities[0]) {
      $scope.$root.buttonClass = 'btn-primary';
      $scope.viewingContext = entity;
    }
    if (entity == $scope.entities[1]) {
      $scope.$root.buttonClass = 'btn-warning';
      $scope.viewingContext = entity;
    }
    if (entity == $scope.entities[2]) {
      $scope.$root.buttonClass = 'btn-danger';
      $scope.viewingContext = entity;
    }
  };
```

The line in the  tag might be the problem!

```
<a ng-class="{'$root.buttonClass':viewingContext=='{{entity}}'}" 
   ng-repeat="entity in entities" 
   ng-click="setContext(entity)" 
   type="">
```

Update:

Attempted to make a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/gn6b4ng8/2

Comment: Try taking the quotes off of $root.buttonClass

Comment: That doesn't seem to work but this does seem right, although it's not loading the classes (might now be a bootstrap CSS issue?) `<a ng-repeat="entity in entities" ng-click="setContext(entity)" ng-class="{'{{$root.buttonClass}}':viewingContext=='{{entity}}'}">
`

Comment: Surely it can't be this hard!?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a dynamic key name in an object. From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass), it looks like you're trying to use the second type of expression, an object, but violating the structure "If the expression evaluates to an object, then for each key-value pair of the object with a truthy value the corresponding key is used as a class name." The key would be used as a class name, as is.

It looks like what you want to be using the first type of expression possible for ng-class "If the expression evaluates to a string, the string should be one or more space-delimited class names." If instead you do something like `ng-class="$root.buttonClass"`. That should solve your problem by then resolving to your class name you store in buttonClass. You can see an example in the documentation where it uses `<p ng-class="style">Using String Syntax</p>`

Comment: If you need the class to only apply to certain entities, you can scope the variable to the entity and set it accordingly in your setContext. If you provide a jsfiddle or something with your code, can help with some direct modifications.

Comment: hmm using `ng-class="$root.buttonClass"` just makes all elements in my ng-repeat equal to the class. Could the problem be that my ng-repeat is in the same tag as my ng-class?

Comment: Yeah, this would fix the conditional name but not the secondary condition of which of the entities to use it on. For that you need a second layer, either a variable that is in each entity that you can set with your setContext or you'd have to go back to the object way with string names (so 'btn-primary' etc) but with complex evaluations for when to add that class, and extract that logic from the function into the ng-class expression. If you can work up a jsfiddle or plunkr, I can better help.

Comment: Hmm I might have tried that, but not sure. I'll try and get a jsfiddle up tomorrow, never done one before so I was a little worried. Thank you!

Comment: Done. Let me know if there's anything missing from that

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `ngClass` will work the way you want it.

Technically you could achieve your goal with `ngClass`, only if you recompile the elements after each change. This way, Angular will apply the changes in the value of `ngClass` to your element.

I don't think it's a nice way to do it.

Luckily, this is Angular, and you can create your own functionality using directives. You can create a directive, let's call it `dynamicClass`, that will have a similar behavior to that of `ngClass`, but will respond to changes in the class name:

```
myApp.directive('dynamicClass', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.$watch(function() {
                return attrs.dynamicClass;
            }, function(newVal, oldVal) {
                var condition = newVal.match(/:(.*?)\}$/)[1];
                var cls = newVal.match(/^\{'?(.*?)'?:/)[1];
                var oldCls = oldVal.match(/^\{'?(.*?)'?:/)[1];
                element.removeClass(oldCls);
                if ($scope.$eval(condition)) {
                    element.addClass(cls);
                }    

            });
        }
    };
});
```

usage:

```
<a dynamic-class="{'{{$root.buttonClass}}':viewingContext=='{{entity}}'}" 
  ng-repeat="entity in entities" 
  ng-click="setContext(entity)">
```

I forked your fiddle to test it. [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/wqytn4Lw/).